# How to determine if this is set is a vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Determine whether the set of all real, continuous functions with the property that the function is $0$ at every integer (e.g. $f(x) = \sin(\pi x)$), is a vector space.

I'm not sure how to define functions which satisfy this set, so I can't even start testing the vector space axioms on them. Could anyone help?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Is a linear combination of such functions in the space?

Comment: Well, suppose $f$ and $g$ are in the set. Is $f+g$ in the set? How about $c\cdot f$ for some constant $c$? By arguing pointwise, it's easy to show that if these two functions are in the set for all $f,g$, then all of the axioms of a vector space are satisfied.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two steps.

1. The set of all functions from $\mathbb{R}\text{ to }\mathbb{R}$ is obviously a vector space with respect to addition and scalar multiplication.
2. Then it is sufficient to show that your set(the set of all real, continuous functions with the property that the function is zero at every integer) is a subspace.

Let the set of interest be $V$. In advance, since $\sin(\pi x)\in V$, $V$ is non-empty. Also, $\forall f,g\in V, f-g\in V$ because $(f-g)(n)=f(n)-g(n)=0,\forall n\in\mathbb{Z}$. Therefore, $V$ is a subspace, which means that it is itself a vector space.

Comment: +1: good answer. Sorry to be picky, but you also need to show that $V$ is non-empty.

Comment: Thanks to your good comment! Yes that must be added as well.